# FlexPrintJob does not print the graphical filters

Tags: apache-flex, printing

If I assign filters in the UIComponent.filters property, they display fine on screen, but they are ignored when I print them through FlexPrintJob.

I've tried DropshadowFilter, BlurFilter, BevelFilter. None of them shows up. I tried all the bitmapCaching modes. Also printAsBitmap.

You can try that by going to the example in the ASDoc for FlexPrintJob. Just assign filters to some of the printed components.

Can you show me how to do that?

I put a filter in the first file:

```
enter code here


FormPrintHeader.mxml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Custom control for the header area of the printed page. -->
<s:VGroup name="FormPrintHeader"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        width="60%"
        horizontalAlign="right" filters="{[new spark.filters.BlurFilter]}">

    <s:Label text="This is a placeholder for first page contents"/>

</s:VGroup>

FormPrintFooter.mxml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Custom control for the footer area of the printed page. -->
<s:VGroup name="FormPrintFooter"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        width="60%"
        horizontalAlign="right" >

    <!-- Declare and initialize the product total variable. -->
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var pTotal:Number = 0;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="Product Total: {pTotal}"/>

</s:VGroup>

FormPrintView.mxml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Custom control to print the Halo DataGrid control on multiple pages. -->
<s:VGroup name="FormPrintView"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        xmlns="*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.*;

            // Declare and initialize the variables used in the component.
            // The application sets the actual prodTotal value.
            [Bindable]
            public var pageNumber:Number = 1;

            [Bindable]
            public var prodTotal:Number = 0;

            // Control the page contents by selectively hiding the header and
            // footer based on the page type.
            public function showPage(pageType:String):void {
                if (pageType == "first" || pageType == "middle") {
                    // Hide the footer.
                    footer.includeInLayout = false;
                    footer.visible = false;
                }
                if (pageType == "middle" || pageType == "last") {
                    // The header won't be used again; hide it.
                    header.includeInLayout = false;
                    header.visible = false;
                }
                if (pageType == "last") {
                    // Show the footer.
                    footer.includeInLayout = true;
                    footer.visible = true;
                }
                //Update the DataGrid layout to reflect the results.
                validateNow();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- The template for the printed page, with the contents for all pages. -->
    <s:VGroup width="80%" horizontalAlign="left">
        <s:Label text="Page {pageNumber}"/>
    </s:VGroup>

    <FormPrintHeader id="header" />

    <!-- The data grid. The sizeToPage property is true by default, so the last
        page has only as many grid rows as are needed for the data. -->
    <mx:PrintDataGrid id="myDataGrid" width="60%" height="100%">
        <!-- Specify the columns to ensure that their order is correct. -->
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Index" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Qty" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:PrintDataGrid>

    <!-- Create a FormPrintFooter control and set its prodTotal variable. -->
    <FormPrintFooter id="footer" pTotal="{prodTotal}" />

</s:VGroup>

PrintDataGridExample.mxml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Main application to print a Halo DataGrid control on multiple pages. -->
<s:Application name="PrintDataGridExample.mxml"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        initialize="initData();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import mx.printing.*;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import FormPrintView;
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

        // Declare variables and initialize simple variables.
        [Bindable]
        public var dgProvider:ArrayCollection;
        public var footerHeight:Number = 20;
        public var prodIndex:Number;
        public var prodTotal:Number = 0;

        // Data initialization.
        public function initData():void {
            // Create the data provider for the DataGrid control.
            dgProvider = new ArrayCollection;
        }

        // Fill the dgProvider ArrayCollection with the specified items.
        public function setdgProvider(items:int):void {
            prodIndex=1;
            dgProvider.removeAll();
            for (var z:int=0; z<items; z++) {
                var prod1:Object = {};
                prod1.Qty = prodIndex * 7;
                prod1.Index = prodIndex++;
                prodTotal += prod1.Qty;
                dgProvider.addItem(prod1);
            }
        }

        // The function to print the output.
        public function doPrint():void {
            var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
            if (printJob.start()) {
                // Create a FormPrintView control as a child of the current view.
                var thePrintView:FormPrintView = new FormPrintView();
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addElement(thePrintView);

                //Set the print view properties.
                thePrintView.width=printJob.pageWidth;
                thePrintView.height=printJob.pageHeight;
                thePrintView.prodTotal = prodTotal;
                // Set the data provider of the FormPrintView component's data grid
                // to be the data provider of the displayed data grid.
                thePrintView.myDataGrid.dataProvider = myDataGrid.dataProvider;
                // Create a single-page image.
                thePrintView.showPage("single");
                // If the print image's data grid can hold all the provider's rows,
                // add the page to the print job.
                if (!thePrintView.myDataGrid.validNextPage)  {
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                }
                // Otherwise, the job requires multiple pages.
                else {
                    // Create the first page and add it to the print job.
                    thePrintView.showPage("first");
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                    thePrintView.pageNumber++;
                    // Loop through the following code until all pages are queued.
                    while (true) {
                        // Move the next page of data to the top of the print grid.
                        thePrintView.myDataGrid.nextPage();
                        thePrintView.showPage("last");
                        // If the page holds the remaining data, or if the last page
                        // was completely filled by the last grid data, queue it for printing.
                        // Test if there is data for another PrintDataGrid page.
                        if (!thePrintView.myDataGrid.validNextPage) {
                            // This is the last page; queue it and exit the print loop.
                            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            // This is not the last page. Queue a middle page.
                            thePrintView.showPage("middle");
                            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                            thePrintView.pageNumber++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // All pages are queued; remove the FormPrintView control to free memory.
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.removeElement(thePrintView);
            }
            // Send the job to the printer.
            printJob.send();
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Panel title="DataGrid Printing Example"
            width="75%" height="75%"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:VGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
            <mx:DataGrid id="myDataGrid" dataProvider="{dgProvider}">
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Index"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Qty"/>
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>

            <s:Label width="100%" color="blue"
                text="Specify the number of lines and click Fill Grid first. Then you can click Print."/>

            <s:TextInput id="dataItems" text="35"/>

            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Button id="setDP" label="Fill Grid" click="setdgProvider(int(dataItems.text));"/>
                <s:Button id="printDG" label="Print" click="doPrint();"/>
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your FormPrintHeader.mxml with below code: -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Custom control for the header area of the printed page. -->
<s:VGroup name="FormPrintHeader"
          xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          width="60%"
          horizontalAlign="right" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
          filters="{[new flash.filters.BlurFilter()]}" creationComplete="addHeaderPrinting(this)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.filters.BlurFilter;

            import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;

            private function addHeaderPrinting(source:IBitmapDrawable):void {
                var imageBitmapData:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(source);
                swfLoader.source = new Bitmap(imageBitmapData);
                mylblPrint.includeInLayout = mylblPrint.visible = false;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Label id="mylblPrint"
             text="This is a placeholder for first page contents. This is a placeholder for first page contents"/>
    <mx:SWFLoader id="swfLoader" >
        <mx:filters>
            <mx:BlurFilter />
        </mx:filters>
    </mx:SWFLoader>
</s:VGroup>
```

Hope this may help you.